# How to define log4j2 config correctly in web,xml

Tags: tomcat, log4j, web.xml, servlet-3.0, jersey-3.0

Trying to use log4j2 within my Jersey3 application (running in a tomcat). I want to load the config through my web.xml as the following:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <!-- ServletContextListeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.something.AppContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
       ...
    </servlet>

    <!-- Log4J -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:config/log4j-dev.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- URL-Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        ...
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Security Roles -->
    <security-role>
      ...
    </security-role>

    <!-- Login Config -->
    <login-config>
        ...
    </login-config>

    <!-- Security Constraints-->
    <security-constraint>
       ...
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

The config file itself, lie in the following structure:

`src/main/resources/config/`

In my properties, I defined a File logger:

**log4j-dev.properties**

```
status = warn
name= properties_configuration

property.basePath = ${sys:catalina.home}/logs/ogd_mdd/

# RollingFileAppender will print logs in file which can be rotated based on time or size
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%M] [%l] - %msg%n

# Configure root logger for logging error logs in classes which are in package other than above specified package
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

**pom.xml**

```
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

All I get is console logs on the ERROR level (seems like the default config was loaded instead of mine). I am sure, I defined the configuration correctly, although made a mistake in the web.xml... How would I need to define the path, to get the properties load correctly?

**debug logs of log4j**

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.163821 seconds to load 218 plugins from ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64

DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=1fb9201c, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@65b40e79]...
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=1fb9201c] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@65b40e79) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 4 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Yaml support, ConfigurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.yaml.YamlConfigurationFactory is inactive
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@5d745e72
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.properties] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.properties] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.properties] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.yml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.yml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.yml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.yaml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.yaml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.yaml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.json] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.json] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.json] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.jsn] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.jsn] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.jsn] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.xml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test1fb9201c.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2-test.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.properties] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.properties] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.properties] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.yml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.yml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.yml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.yaml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.yaml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.yaml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.json] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.json] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.json] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.jsn] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.jsn] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.jsn] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.xml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j21fb9201c.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.yaml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.json] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.json] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.json] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.json] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.jsn] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using context class loader ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ogd_mdd_backend_app
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@32d2fa64
 class loader.
TRACE StatusLogger Trying to find [log4j2.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
WARN StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2
DEBUG StatusLogger Apache Log4j Core 2.14.0 initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3d8505f8
DEBUG StatusLogger Installed 0 script engines
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 123 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3d8505f8 initialized
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3d8505f8
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3d8505f8 OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@76770ca9...
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger OutputStream closed
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@76770ca9 OK
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@1803ce84
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering context (1/1): '1fb9201c' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@65b40e79
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=StatusLogger'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=ContextSelector'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=Loggers,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=Appenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=StatusLogger
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=ContextSelector
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1fb9201c,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
TRACE StatusLogger Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=1fb9201c] at URI NULL_SOURCE (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@65b40e79) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=1fb9201c, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@65b40e79] started OK.
```

Comment: Can you set the system property `log4j.debug` to `true` and add the output of the status logger to your question?

Comment: The key message is _"Not in a ServletContext environment"_ . If you have an `<absolute-ordering>` in your `web.xml` to save-up some startup time you need to add `<name>log4j</name>` to it.

Comment: Hm, I don't have something like this - could it be that the ServletContextListener has something to do with it? (updated the full web.xml to the question)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the Jersey **3** part of your question, which means you are using Tomcat **10**. The current version of `log4j-web` does not work with Jakarta EE 9.0, however you can _"jakartify"_ the library using [Tomcat's Migration Tool](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi).

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong value for the `log4jConfiguration` parameter: `file:///config/log4j-dev.properties` points to the file `/config/log4j-dev.properties` of your local file system.

Since `log4jConfiguration` can be either a resource path to pass to [`ServletContext#getResource`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletcontext#getResource-java.lang.String-) or an absolute URI, you can use:

- either the path of the file relative to the web applications root: `/WEB-INF/classes/config/log4j-dev.properties`,
- a classpath URI: `classpath:config/log4j-dev.properties`.

**Edit**: there is also a little problem with your configuration: it lacks a triggering policy:

```
status = warn
name= properties_configuration

property.basePath = ${sys:catalina.base}/logs/ogd_mdd/

# RollingFileAppender will print logs in file which can be rotated based on time or size
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.policy.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%M] [%l] - %msg%n

# Configure root logger for logging error logs in classes which are in package other than above specified package
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately it did not help - do I miss something in the web.xml? It seems context-param is not recognized...

Comment: Did you add `log4j-web.jar` to your dependencies? Is your `web.xml` version 3.0 or higher?

Comment: Yep, I've added the dependencies for log4j2 in my pom.xml in my question. Should be correct, right?

Comment: Should be alright. You can set the system property `log4j2.debug` to `true` to check if the file was read or not.

Comment: All the logs says now, that it couldn't find the configuration file... web.xml has version 4.0.